# A simple Markdown viewer for Windows (without an editor)

Tags: windows, gui, offline, markdown, documentation-viewer

I'm looking for a markdown viewer that does not offer editing capabilities that can be run on some local markdown files. The idea is to provide users an easy way to view some documentation without making it easy for them to edit it.

I've seen the answer to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/71013/simple-open-source-offline-markdown-viewer-for-windows), but all of the recommendations are for editors that include viewers.

It's OK if it's a browser plug-in, but since not everyone uses the same browser I would prefer if it weren't.

Comment: There is an old tool which might be ideal for you. Here is the link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/markdown-reader-lt/

Answer (score 2):

There is a browser extension: [markdown-viewer](https://github.com/simov/markdown-viewer) that has chrome, opera, and firefox versions.

Be aware that markdown files are text files and can be edited very easily

Answer (score 2):

There is a gratis and open-source extension for File Explorer on Windows 10 that enables Markdown file previews. From https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/enable-markdown-file-previews-in-file-explorer-on-windows-10/amp/:

> In order to enable Markdown file previews in File Explorer, you will need to [install an extension for File Explorer](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/install-uninstall-file-explorer-extensions-on-windows-10/). This particular extension is included with [PowerToys](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/get-powertoys-on-windows-10/), a free open-source tool that has been developed by Microsoft. You can [download it from Github](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys).
>
> PowerToys feature several tools and they are useful but if you aren’t interested in using them all, you can choose to enable only the ‘File Explorer’ feature. Once it is enabled, you will need to restart File Explorer before the extension will start working. To restart File Explorer, open Task Manager and look for Windows Explorer in the Processes tab. Select it, and click the Restart button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A pity there's no portable version of this. At my current work place I'm not allowed to *install* software, but I'm permitted to *run* stand-alone (portable) apps. I'd love to give this one a try…

Answer (score 0):

There is an old tool which might be ideal for you.

Here is the link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/markdown-reader-lt/

This tool only allows you to view and Not edit the md files just as you need.
Here is a screenshot of tool:
[image]